# Writing unit tests for database hits

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm a complete beginner to writing unit tests.  I am building an app with AngularJS, NodeJS, and MySQL.  I have just setup and configured Karma.  My very basic question is, how do I unit test CRUD functions?  For example, this is my angular 'add' function:

```
$scope.add = function (first_name, last_name, email) {
    if (!first_name || first_name === '') {
        $scope.error = true;
        $scope.errorMsg = "Missing first name";
        return;
    }
    if (!last_name || last_name === '') {
        $scope.error = true;
        $scope.errorMsg = "Missing last name";
        return;
    }
    if (!email || email === '') {
        $scope.error = true;
        $scope.errorMsg = "Missing email";
        return;
    }
    if (!validEmail(email)) {
        $scope.error = true;
        $scope.errorMsg = "Email format invalid";
        return;
    }

    $scope.savingPromise = user.add(first_name, last_name, email).then(
        function (response) {
            $scope.newID = response.insertID;
            return;
        },
        function (error) {
            // Some error
        }
    );
}
```

'user' is a service that sends a message to NodeJS to insert into the database.

I expect user.add to fail if there's something wrong with Node, the database, or if email is duplicated.

Can someone help me get started with how Jasmine would look for add, delete, get, update, or point me to some documentation?  I've read lots, but nothing yet covering how to test database access.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would separate in to two methods one is the responsible of making the validations the second one the service the saves to DB.

```
$scope.add(user) {
  validationService.Validate(user); // add unit test support to this service
  userDataservice.Store(user);
}
```

You can easily add support to your validations unit tests.

If you want to test the whole pipe (client >> service >> database), imho is not a unit test, it's more integration (you are hitting a real service + real database), you could think about using protractor or something like that and record and end to end test.